# type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<MSEventH>' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart

So I am getting this error recently. I always specify the Type, so I don't know why I am getting this error..
the code that I am using is the following 
Any help is appreciated

```
  List<MSEvent> fetchEvents();
  Future<void> cacheEvents(List<MSEvent> events);
}
class MSEventLocalSourceImpl implements MSEventLocalSource {
  List<MSEventH> convertList(List<MSEventH> hevents) {
    List<MSEventH> eventList = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < hevents.length; i++) {
      eventList.add(hevents[i]);
    }
    return eventList;
  }
  final localStorageService = locator<LocalStorageService>();
  @override
  List<MSEvent> fetchEvents() {
    List<MSEvent> eventList = [];
    Iterable<List<MSEventH>> heventLists = localStorageService.eventsBox.values;
    List<MSEventH> heventList = heventLists.first;
    if (localStorageService.eventsBox.isEmpty) {
      throw CacheException('No events found in cache');
    }
    try{
      heventList.forEach((eventh) => eventList.add(MSEvent.fromMSEventH(eventh)));
    } catch(e){
      print(e);
    }
    return eventList;
  }
  @override
  Future<void> cacheEvents(List<MSEvent> events) async {
    List<MSEventH> eventList = [];
    events.forEach((event) => eventList.add(MSEventH.fromMSEvent(event)));
    await localStorageService.eventsBox.add(eventList);
  }
}
```

Comment: sounds like a variance issue. If `List<MSEventH> heventList = heventLists.first;` is throwing the error, try creating a new List with `List<MSEventH>.from(heventLists.first)`. In short you can't convert a List<dynamic> to List<MSEventH>, since Dart does not know, if the dynamic items are actually MSEventH. [Here](https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-declaration-site-variance-5c0e9c5f18a5) is a good read about the topic

Comment: Can you share the code of LocalStorageService ? I think that the problem is localStorageService.eventsBox.values returning a list that doesnt specify the type, maybe you shuld use generics on the LocalStorageService.

Comment: Also, can you let us know which specific line it's telling you the problem is coming from?  That might help us to identify any particular issues, thank you.

Comment: List<MSEventH> heventList = heventLists.first; this line is throwing the error. localStorageService.eventsBox.values is returning an iterable of List<MSEventH>. That's why I am taking the first.